# Spot the differance between nearly two identical HTML emails

Tags: html, email, gmail

This has me perplexed. I have these two emails (below). One with a sidebar, and one without a sidebar. The one with sidebar, is formatted correctly when it is received in gmail. The one without sidebar is not. It loses background color and some other formatting, etc. Displaying it in broswer works fine.

My question is what do i need to change on the email without sidebar to have it show correctly?

Email with sidebar: shows correctly

http://pastie.org/1648139.js

Email without sidebar: shows incorrectly.

http://pastie.org/1648144.js

Need help spotting the issue. 
Thanks!

Comment: dude you really expect us to pour through that source and try and find what the problem is?  Try using chrome's dev tools or firefoxes to isolate the problem

Comment: Have you tried `diff`? Nobody wants to dredge through a thousand lines of unformatted HTML to "spot the difference" for you.

Comment: I'm sure Nate appreciates the warm Stack Overflow welcome all of the downvoters have given his first question.  Criminy ...

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted this line:

```
document.write("                                <span class=\'meta meta_tag meta_tag_inline meta_tag_inline_any meta_tag_inline_any_html\'>&lt;/<span class=\'entity entity_name entity_name_tag entity_name_tag_inline entity_name_tag_inline_any entity_name_tag_inline_any_html\'>table<\/span>&gt;<\/span>\n");
```

Add it in the new file after line 128

As a side note, it would be much easier to review the final html output of the emails and you wouldn't get such a negative reaction.

Comment: Thanks guys, Sorry it was frustrating for me two, since I did actaully scan the code, just not good enough i guess. So thats why i asked.

Comment: @nate sorry your 1st question was met with such hostility. The SO Community can be extremely helpful, but we aren't magic (or friendly apparently). Generally, if you can show you have spent the time trying to narrow the issue down, you can get a reasonable answer. For things like this using a tool like [ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) can help you track it down. That's what I used, but the above is just a guess. It appears you have an unclosed Table tag which can cause the kind of behavior you're seeing. If not that table, probably some other unclosed tag is the culprit.